# How to get password of the network connection i'm currently connected to

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-8-preview, password-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the wifi password stored somewhere in windows-7?](https://superuser.com/questions/424624/is-the-wifi-password-stored-somewhere-in-windows-7)

I've got win 7 and win 8 installed on the PC. Win 7 automatically connects to my router and it saved the password somewhere, but I got no idea where. I want win 8 to connect to the same network, but there's the key/password it want me to type in when i try to connect.

How can I get that? I'm on win 7 right now

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: I think the OP wants his Win 8 instance to auto connect to a wireless network that his Win 7 instance already connects to. I have only used win 8 a small amount, and it was virtualized so I didn't deal with wireless. Regardless though, if you are the owner, or know the owner of the wireless network, put in the key, I would think, like most OS's, it will save once it is put in there. If you don't know the key, you cannot connect.

Comment: Enter the key/passphrase as you did in windows 7

Answer (score 12):

The following shows you exactly where to get the key, assuming you know your network name (SSID):

[image]

[image]

[image]