# How to decrypt passwords in the XML files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, passwords, xml

As per this superuser question with 130,000 views, its possible to view wireless passwords in plaintext (as admin) using the below command.

```
netsh wlan export profile interface=wi-fi key=clear folder=c:\
```

[Is the wifi password stored somewhere in windows-7?](https://superuser.com/questions/424624/is-the-wifi-password-stored-somewhere-in-windows-7)

I just learned it's possible to read data relating to wireless networks in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces` as a user with normal privileges. The only problem is: the "keyMaterial" is encrypted. I came across this article:

https://www.purehacking.com/blog/vitaly-nikolenko/extracting-wireless-wep/wpa/wpa2-preshared-keys/passwords-from-windows-7

In the article the author talks about using `CryptStringToBinary()` and `CryptUnprotectData()` functions to view the keyMaterial in plaintext. But I have *no clue* what any of that means. I'm looking for a simplified answer and possibly how to view the passwords in the XML files.

How do we decrypt the keyMaterial in the XML files found in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces`?

Comment: By using `netsh` or supplying those strings to the appropriate functions (two of which you possibly named). If you don't know how to code just use the `netsh` command (assuming it works).